# NHibernate: Filtering a child collection which includes a join

Tags: nhibernate, criteria-api, hbm

I have the following mapping files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MyAssembly" namespace="EntityNamespace">
  <class name="Server" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" table="tblServer" >
    <id name="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <bag name="Services" cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="true">
           <key column="Id" />
      <one-to-many class="Service" />
      <filter name="currentServices" condition=":currentDate BETWEEN DtStart AND DtEnd" />
    </bag>

  </class>

  <filter-def name="currentServices">
    <filter-param name="currentDate" type="System.DateTime"/>
  </filter-def>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="MyAssembly" namespace="EntityNamespace">
  <class name="Service" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" table="tblService" >
    <id name="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Server" column="server_id" />

    <join table="tblServiceOptMatrix">
      <key column="ServiceOptID" />
      <property name="StartDate" column="DtStart" type="DateTime" />
      <property name="EndDate" column="DtEnd" type="DateTime" />
    </join>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the following criteria API:

```
IList<Server> servers;
using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Session.EnableFilter("currentServices")
        .SetParameter("currentDate", DateTime.Now);
    servers = Session.CreateCriteria<Server>()
        .List<Server>();
    tx.Commit();
}
```

and the sql that is generated for lazily retrieving services looks like this:

```
SELECT service0_.server_id as server2_1_,
       service0_.id        as id1_,
       service0_1_.DtStart as DtStart256_0_,
       service0_1_.DtEnd   as DtEnd256_0_
FROM   tblTfopt valueadded0_
       inner join tblServiceOptMatrix service0_1_
         on service0_.id = service0_1_.ServiceOptID
WHERE  '2010-01-07T14:58:09.00' /* @p0 */ 
    BETWEEN service0_.DtStart AND service0_.DtEnd
       and service0_.server_id = 993 /* @p1 */
```

where the server id and date are examples. The problem is that the sql produced for the filter is using the wrong table alias, It should instead be this:

```
BETWEEN service0_1_.DtStart AND service0_1_.DtEnd
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?